# Can't connect to SQL Anywhere 12 with PHP and ODBC on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, odbc, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to get a PHP 5.3.10 installation on Ubuntu 12.04 to connect to a a remote SQL Anywhere 12 (Sybase?) server using ODBC (unixODBC). However, PHP's execution halts at odbc_connect().

**PHP code:**

```
$odbc = odbc_connect('DSN=TP189902;', 'username', 'password');

if ($odbc)
{
    echo 'Connected';
}
else
{
    echo 'Failed: '.odbc_error($odbc);
}
```

So regardless of whether or not it connects, it should be outputting one of the echos, but it doesn't. If I try using PHP's PDO library instead, I get the same result.

My unixODBC setup looks like the following. And this might be where my mistake is, because I've never setup ODBC on linux before and am not very familiar with it.

**odbcinst.ini**

```
[SQL Anywhere 12]
Description = SQL Anywhere 12
Driver = /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so
Setup  = /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so
```

**odbc.ini**

```
[TP189902]
Description = TP189902
Uid = username
Pwd = password
Driver = SQL Anywhere 12
ServerName = 189902
CommLinks = tcpip(Host=1.2.3.4)
DatabaseName = DB189902
```

I've also tried a ton of alternatives, such as using the driver's path for the Driver value, using Host=1.2.3.4 instead of CommLinks, etc.

Also the command `isql -v TP189902 username password` doesn't output anything unless I give it a fake DSN so that it outputs and error.

I've also verified that libdbodbc12.so is the same architecture as isql and that it has all of it's dependencies.

On top of this, I have very similar setup on a Windows 7 machine running WAMP, that connects just fine (with both the ODBC and PDO library). I used the same DSN details on it.

Edit: I've also tried this to skip the DSN, but it gives the same result. It also works on the Windows box.

```
$odbc = odbc_connect('Driver={SQL Anywhere 12};Server=189902;CommLinks=tcpip(Host=1.2.3.4);', 'username', 'password');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the issue was getting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64 for Apache.

Setting it in /etc/environment got isql -v TP189902 and php connect.php working when called from any shell user, but not Apache.

To get Apache to see it, I had to edit /etc/init.d/apache2 and change
    `ENV="env -i LANG=C PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"`
to
`ENV="env -i LANG=C PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64"`.
And then restart the Apache service.
Various other methods I found online to do this did not work.

One caveat is that with the path set, unixODBC still won't read my system DSN file for some reason. So to get Apache to access the DSN, I had to make a user DSN file (.odbc.ini) in /var/www, as that's the Apache user's (www-data) home folder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use PHP these days but here are some things I've spotted:

1. I would totally ignore php until you get isql working.
2. I'm assuming it is a typo that you say your system ini file is "odbcinstr.ini" - it should be "odbcinst.ini".
3. How do you know you are looking at the right odbc ini files - run odbcinst -j to check the locations unixODBC is using.
4. I know where that "[ODBC Data Sources]" section comes from (iodbc) but it not at all necessary for unixODBC - just delete the first 2 lines of your odbc.ini file.
5. your isql line is probably missing a username and password - it should be "isql -v TP189902 username password". I cannot for the life of me see why it would output nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Splitting up the following due to character limit...
1. Every time I make a change and try again I try both php and isql because I wasn't sure if isql was supposed to output anything. 
2. Yes, that's a typo in the post, but the actual file name is spelled correctly.

Comment: 3. I've done that too. The only thing is that it specifies ~/.odbc.ini as a user DSN file and /etc/odbc.ini as a system DSN. I've been using the system DSN file because that's what I used on the Windows box too. I'm not sure if it matters. 
4. I tried both with and without it. I'll remove it for good though.
5. I tried that a few times, but I was under the impression that having the username and password in the DSN config would make it not need it on the isql command. I try not to type out password text in shell commands, but I will test with that from now on.

Comment: Do an isql -v TP189902 username password and tell me what happens. You should get either an error or a prompt to enter SQL. If you get neither run strace -o x.log isql -v TP189902 username password and post the log file somewhere I can see it.

Comment: It opens /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so successfully but libdbodbc12_r.so from various places and fails. Run ldd on /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so and it should show you what it depends on and what is missing.

Comment: I've done that on both files and it doesn't say anything is missing.

Comment: Let me see ldd output on /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so and then if it does in fact list where libdbodbc12_r.so is located run an ls -la on_that_file to see permissions.

Comment: It doesn't list libdbodbc12_r.so: http://pastebin.com/UZxRxiLL But libdbodbc12_r.so is in the same directory.

Comment: Your strace clearly showed something (the dynamic linker) repeatedly trying to find libdbodbc12_r.so and failing. Usually a _r denotes a thread-safe version of a library.if this helps. There must be a reference/dependency to this lib somewhere you just have not found it yet. Try making sure the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/ and exporting it before running isql.

Comment: Ok, now it works with the variable set, but only on that user and from ~/.odbc.ini. It seems to completely ignore /etc/odbc.ini. I need it to work with any user since php runs from a different user.

Comment: Also running `odbcinst -j` as a user now returns `odbcinst: symbol lookup error: odbcinst: undefined symbol: odbcinst_system_file_name`, but it works normally as root/sudo.

Comment: After more digging and having to mess with library paths and environmental variables I'm close to getting it working. The simple PHP script I posted above is working, but the PHP framework I'm using for a project won't connect, so my question isn't relevant anymore. Thanks for your help bohica. It helped me get closer to getting it fully working.